# jQuery Autofill Form Fields with Values From Two Others

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Let's say I have a form like this

Username
Nickname
First Name
Last Name

I want the First + Last Name fields to automatically populate the Username and Nickname fields.

Result: Username = First + Last Name -- Nickname = First + Last Name

Here is what I have so far

```
<script>

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#field_5, #field_6").on("blur",function(){
      getname();
    }); 
  });

  function getname(){
    $('#Field_2, #field_1').val($('#field_5').val()+" "+$('#field_6').val());
  }
</script>
```

WHERE Field 5 = First Name, Field 6 = Last Name, Field_2 = Username and Field_1 = Nickname

Comment: Did you want it to auto populate as each key is pressed? Or when the user clicks out of the input box?

Comment: When the user clicks out of the box. Either one will do, actually.

Comment: @Aliyah, in updated code there is extra braces `}); })`

Comment: Thanx, will remove these and let you know if it works.

Comment: Updated answer, still having an issue. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/FFLYE/1/)**

**html**

```
<input type='text' id='fname' value='' />
<input type='text' id='lname' value='' />
<input type='text' id='nickname' value='' />
<input type='text' id='uname' value='' />
```

**jquery/javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#field_5, #field_6").on("blur", getname);
});

function getname(){
$('#nickname, #uname').val($('#fname').val()+" "+$('#lname').val());
}
```

Comment: Hey, Im new to fiddle. How to I see the results? Do I hit "run" ?

Comment: Hey, im testing this using my own ID's and its not working so let me update my question to show you  the code I have in there

Comment: Excellent. The Demo works well. I need to add it to my own site now. I'm wrapping my Jquery in "no conflict" mode. Check the code in my question for me and see if thats wrapped properly

Comment: I think the problem is the wrapper. How should I wrap this? In a simple <script tag?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Answer was wrong before.

Here is the updated version with keyup.

http://jsfiddle.net/79Wb9/3/

Just click run and enjoy.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what #a and #b represents?

Comment: #a and #b are the input fields. So each input has and ID attribute, you can select that element by #IDNAME (in my instance a & b).

I did also realise a small bug with this code, which is more of a usability issue, but if I were to fill in my name, edit my username, then realised my name was wrong and changed it. The username would be set to my name again.

Comment: Ok Im with you now as I have seen the demo, but can you  make another demo based on my question? I have 4 fields

Comment: done, sorry I misread the question before. All fixed now, really easy to implement.

Comment: Gah! I actually figured it out myself (I was missing a $) but I gave the answer to the other guy because I used his code. :/